# Use nth-child value as a SASS variable

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

Is there any way to use the `nth-child` value as a SASS variable ?

Examples of use :

```
div:nth-child(n) {
    content: '#{$n}'
}
```

```
div:nth-child(n) {
    background: rgb(#{$n}, #{$n}, #{$n});
}
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do exactly that. But you can use `@for` directive to loop through a known number of elements:

```
$elements: 15;
@for $i from 0 to $elements {
  div:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) {
     background: rgb($i, $i, $i);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing today, would be nice to find a way to do this on an unknown number of elements.

Comment: is there a way to set `$elements` dynamically according to how many elements there are in your generated DOM?

Comment: @gwho you can't do that since CSS doesn't know about what's in the DOM.

Comment: I worked around this by simply assigning unique id's and referencing those.

Comment: Nice snippet, thanks a lot. But for me worked normally only when I've replaced "from 0 to $elements" => "from 1 to $elements + 1" and "rgb(#{$i},..." -> "rgb($i,...". Not sure if my version of sass has to do with the latter issue.

Comment: @ahnbizcad, there does exist a convoluted way to get DOM information set as SASS vars, if you compile your sass server side. Which is a terrible idea. http://viget.com/extend/sharing-data-between-sass-and-javascript-with-json

Comment: can you do this in a media query?

Comment: Needed to use `:nth-child(#{$i + 1})` as `nth-child` starts at 1, not 0

Comment: you saved my life i needed to add the column with the number of child for a project :)

Answer (score 8):

You could use a mixin like this:

```
 @mixin child($n) {
     &:nth-child(#{$n}){
           background-color:rgb($n,$n,$n);
     }
 }

 div{
     @include child(2);
    }
```

The compiled css looks like:

```
div:nth-child(2) {
   background-color: #020202;
}
```

See an example [here](http://cdpn.io/zjqIn)

Comment: Thanks, but the goal is to avoid multiple similar lines.

Comment: Still dependent on explicit arguments passed in, but still better than completely manual! Thanks!