# SASS to loop through unknown number of elements

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to use Sass to loop through x number of elements, when the number of elements is unknown. I'm not sure if this is possible, and so I'm asking if people can look at the two cases below and offer some insight on how (if) they might be accomplished.

First, I would like to do something like this:

```
@each $slide in $slides {
  #slide-right#{$i} {
    left: 1px;
  }
}
```

to output something like:

```
#slide-right0 {
  left: 1px;
}
#slide-right1 {
  left: 1px;
}
#slide-right2 {
  left: 1px;
}
```

...etc.

Second, I want to take the following CSS and turn it into some kind of loop for code brevity:

```
#slide0 {
  order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
}
#slide-right0 {
  order: 2;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
}
#slide1 {
  order: 3;
  -webkit-order: 3;
  -ms-flex-order: 3;
}
#slide-right1 {
  order: 4;
  -webkit-order: 4;
  -ms-flex-order: 4;
}
```

...etc.

Essentially:

`#slide0` gets the order of 1

`#slide1` gets an order of 3

...etc. (all odd order numbers)

and

`#slide-right0` gets the order of 2

`#slide-right1` gets the order of 4

...etc. (all even order numbers)

Can a loop be set up to account for 12 slides? How about an unknown number of slides?

Just trying to see if there's a Sass way to do this. Any and all tips appreciated!

Comment: Alternate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120399/use-nth-child-value-as-a-sass-variable

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your needs:

```
$startIndex: 0;
$numSlides: 12;
$order: 0;

@for $i from $startIndex through $numSlides {

  #slide-right#{$i} {
    left: 1px;
  }

}

@for $i from $startIndex through $numSlides {

  $order: $order + 1;

  #slide#{$i} {
    order: #{$order};
    -webkit-order: #{$order};
    -ms-flex-order: #{$order};
  }

  $order: $order + 1;

  #slide-right#{$i} {
    order: #{$order};
    -webkit-order: #{$order};
    -ms-flex-order: #{$order};
  }

}
```

You can copy this code an run it in [sassmeister](http://www.sassmeister.com/) to see the output.

Check out this [sass cheatsheet](https://github.com/miguelmota/sass-cheatsheet) for control directives.

Comment: BOOM! This works beautifully, thank you. Is it possible to set a loop like this up when the number of slides is unknown?

Comment: @amoeboar no, but you can just set a high number, the max num of slides you think will ever exist.

Comment: OK thanks! Just so that I'm clear, would that compile extra CSS that I don't actually need and make my stylesheet bigger?

Comment: @amoeboar yes, if you don't want that then you'd have to add the dynamic css with javascript. I wouldn't worry about the size of the stylesheet unless it's thousands of slides