# How to iterate through each parent list items in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just started working with jQuery and I'm running into a bit of a snag with iterating through each parent UL's list items.

I have a simple accordion menu where I'm adding transition-delay inline style to each individual list item. The issue I have is that I'm not sure how to iterate through each set of parent's list items.

Below is an example of what is occurring on every list item.

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li style="transition-delay: 0ms;></li>
    <li style="transition-delay: 25ms;>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li style="transition-delay: 50ms;>
            <li style="transition-delay: 75ms;>
            <li style="transition-delay: 100ms;>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="transition-delay: 125ms;></li>
    <li style="transition-delay: 150ms;></li>
    <li style="transition-delay: 175ms;></li>
</ul>
```

This is what I'm looking to achieve:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li style="transition-delay: 0ms;></li>
    <li style="transition-delay: 25ms;>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li style="transition-delay: 0ms;>
            <li style="transition-delay: 25ms;>
            <li style="transition-delay: 50ms;>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li style="transition-delay: 50ms;></li>
    <li style="transition-delay: 75ms;></li>
    <li style="transition-delay: 100ms;></li>
</ul>
```

This is what my jQuery looks like:

```
$('ul.mobile-menu li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu li').each(function(i){
    $(this).css({ 'transition-delay': (i*25)+"ms" });
});
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated as I am just getting started with jQuery. I created a codepen so you can see the menu in action and visually see the issue.

http://codepen.io/creativenauts/pen/wGLqPg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach:

```
$('.sub-menu').each(function() {
  // $(this) = single ul element
  $(this).children('li').each(function(idx, el){
    // idx = index of current list [0 ... number]
    // $(el) = single li element
    $(el).css('transition-delay', (idx * 25) + 'ms');
  });
});
```

But in this use case (w.r.t. the size of the list) you can and should use CSS, [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20120654/1293700).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the css method a shot here soon. Ideally, I don't see list items going above more than 10 items and this seems to be a cleaner method without using javascript. Thanks for the post!

Comment: In addition changing the DOM (with javascript) would block the rendering process.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/), which gives an element's position among its siblings:

```
$('ul.mobile-menu li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu li').each(function(){
    $(this).css({ 'transition-delay': ($(this).index()*25)+"ms" });
});
```

Comment: Because `.index()` returns its index in its parent's children, which makes it reset to zero as wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$('ul.mobile-menu li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu').each(function(j, subMenu){
    $(subMenu).children('li').each(function(i, li){ 
        $(li).css('transition-delay', (i*25)+'ms') 
    })
});
```

Comment: That does the trick. when you use function(i,li) how does that work exactly? I see you using $(li).css - possibly could you explain the process so I can understand it a bit better? Thanks again!

Comment: I think I understand it now. So instead of doing for each on LI you're doing it on the sub-menu and then doing another for each on the children LI of the sub-menu. Make sense to me now.

Comment: Or `$('ul.mobile-menu li.menu-item-has-children ul.sub-menu li').css('transition-delay', function(i) { return (i * 25) + 'ms'; });`

Comment: Actually, no, my last comment makes `i` increase across all the iterations.

Comment: that are just the function-arguments: the index, and the particular li-node. The trick does the part before that. I don't select all `LI`'s at once, but `UL` by `UL`