# How do I base a CSS property on an element's :nth-child-count in the DOM?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, sass

I am coding a fullscreen slideshow of elements that are crossfaded in and out of view. I achieve the crossfade effect by animating the opacity of the elements combined with an animation delay.

My HTML is as follows:

```html
<div class="state state-sliding" id="slides">
    <slide class="slide">
        <video  autoplay="" muted="" loop="" class="slide-content"></video>
    </slide>
    <slide class="slide">
        <video  autoplay="" muted="" loop="" class="slide-content"></video>
    </slide>
    <slide class="slide">
        <img  alt="slide image" class="slide-content" src="...">
    </slide>
    <slide class="slide">
        <img  alt="slide image" class="slide-content" src="...">
    </slide>
</div>
```

I use this vanilla CSS to animate my elements:

```css
.slide .slide-content, #slides .slide {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#slides .slide-content {
  background: #000;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(1);
  animation: crossFade 24s infinite;
} 

#slides .slide:nth-child(3) .slide-content{ animation-delay: 6s }
#slides .slide:nth-child(2) .slide-content{ animation-delay: 12s }
#slides .slide:nth-child(1) .slide-content{ animation-delay: 18s }
```

The *animation-delay* property causes the slides to be faded to 100% opacity one by one, creating the desired effect.

**The problem**

This works great when there are exactly four child nodes in the #slides div. How do I make this work for *n* number of children in the #slides div?

The *animation-delay* property *s* should be equal to *nth-child(n)* multiplied by the time per slide:

*animation-delay (s)* = *no. of child in div (n)* * time per slide

I have no idea how to go about implementing this in CSS or SASS. A gentle nudge in the right direction would be very helpful.

**EDIT**

I've solved my problem by using angularjs' [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive. This is my  component:

```
<img ng-if="$ctrl.type === 'image'" ng-src="{{$ctrl.source}}" alt="slide image" class="slide-content" ng-style="{'animation': 'crossFade ' + {{$ctrl.total*6}} +'s infinite ', 'animation-delay': {{$ctrl.child*6}}+'s'}">

<video ng-if="$ctrl.type === 'video'" autoplay muted loop class="slide-content" ng-src="{{$ctrl.source}}" ng-style="{'animation': 'crossFade ' + {{$ctrl.total*6}} +'s infinite ', 'animation-delay': {{$ctrl.child*6}}+'s'}">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Is it possible to improve on this? I'd have to conditionally set the animation points of the *@keyframes* CSS style as well

Comment: Hi @matthiasdv,
I think you can get hnit from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120399/use-nth-child-value-as-a-sass-variable

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Seems what I'm asking for is impossible to do. I wonder why

Comment: @matthiasdv It's unclear what you mean. You want the CSS to automatically generate/change based on how many HTML elements you have? You'll need JavaScript for that.

Comment: @TylerH: I believe your interpretation is correct.

Comment: @TylerH: That's correct. I think I'll be able to solve this using angularjs' ng-style directive

Comment: @matthiasdv there is no straight forward way to pass daynamic value to CSS.
At the best you can do is create CSS style dynamically when in your HTML at run time or use some other way of passing values to CSS file. May be you can use ng-style of angularjs.

Comment: @matthiasdv If you like, you can edit your question to include the angularjs and/or JavaScript tags. That way someone could come along and provide a solution you may not think of using some hybrid of CSS and JS.

Comment: @TylerH that's actually quite helpful; I think I'll do just that!

Answer (score 0):

if you know that the slider will never contains more that `n` elements, you can generate a series long enough to accomodate the "worst case"
Although not particularly elegant, it allows you to avoid javascript.
It is easy to do with SASS

```
$delay: 6s;
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
  #slides .slide:nth-child(#{$i}) .slide-content{ animation-delay: $delay * $i }
}
```

or with a mixin

```
@mixin slide-delay($children, $delay: 0s) {
  @for $i from 1 through $children {
    #slides .slide:nth-child(#{$i}) .slide-content{ animation-delay: $delay * $i }
  }
}

@include slide-delay(4, 1s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Javascript** with the current markup you can do the following:

```
//Get Slides NodeList
var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide-content');

//Make Array and reverse.
var slidesReversed = Array.prototype.slice.call(slides).reverse();

//Set Animation Delay for each slide.
for (var i = slidesReversed.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  slidesReversed[i].style.animationDelay = i * 6 + 's';
}
```