# How to get html element's child position inside child's css class declaration

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is it possible to get child's position (1,2,3... or n) inside child's css class?

```
<div class="parent">
<span class="child">Hi<span> 
<span class="child">Hello<span>
<span class="child">How are you?<span>
</div>
```

Here for e.g., If I want to set 100px width for first child(HI), second child 200px, third child 300px respectively and want to write css using some multiplier would be really great. Is it possible to write CSS like below?

```
div.parent > span:nth-child(){
width: (n * 100)px;
}
```

Comment: no it's impossible, you need to use SASS

Comment: you mean like this? ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20120399/use-nth-child-value-as-a-sass-variable

Comment: I take it that the childs text content is the factor in determining the width you'd wish to place on the child?

Answer (score 1):

No, CSS doesn't have such ability. You'd have to either create separate style for each case, or use a custom `--myvar` variable and supply it for each element:

```css
div.parent > span {
  width: calc(var(--i) * 60px);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: pink;
}

div.parent > span:after
{
  counter-reset: i calc(var(--i) * 60);
  content: counter(i);
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<span class="child" style="--i:1;">Hi</span> 
<span class="child" style="--i:2;">Hello</span>
<span class="child" style="--i:3;">How are you?</span>
<span class="child" style="--i:4;">Bye</span>
</div>
```